# Stuck PHP date() shows same day/time

Tags: date, php

I'm currently having the strangest issue. I have the following php code which should render the current day and date but it's giving me "Mon, Dec 12, 2010" no matter what day it is.

```
<?php echo date('D, M n, Y'); ?>
```

if I run

```
<?php echo date(); ?>
```

It doesn't return anything.

I'm running PHP Version 5.2.13 via fastcgi on lighttpd (managed by Kloxo).  My timezone is correctly set on the server (CentOS 5.5).

I don't know if this is a server problem or a php.ini problem so I'm posting here. Please move if necessary.

Comment: Run `date` in a terminal to see if your system clock is correctly set.

Comment: Is your web page cached perhaps?

Comment: If I run <?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?> (example from php.net) it returns Monday 27th of December 2010 07:04:44 PM which at the time of this writing is the exact time.

Comment: date is correct in terminal.  And the webpage is not cached as I have both the date format above (in comment) and the format in the question on the same page. The strange thing is that the format in the question used to work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'D, M n, Y'` means *"textual representation of day, short textual representation of month, **numeric representation of month**, year"*. So, yes, December is the twelfth month, hence `'n'` will be 12. All throughout December. :)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Really? Yes, you are right! OK, I really feel dumb now! This isn't my first day coding php, really!

Comment: @Jon *Psst, blame it on the holidays! Wink wink, nudge nudge...*

Comment: Just used date('D, M j, Y') and everything works great! Sorry long day and longer weekend still doesn't justify not checking that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = 1293501872;
echo date('D, M n, Y', $time);

echo date("Y.m.d H:i:s", $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
```

Check what date it returns.
echo time() not date().

Comment: @marcog, My mistake, that's not what I intended.

Comment: Returned Mon, Dec 12, 2010 for the first one; 2010.12.27 19:23:23 for the second one; and anything echoing time() returned just 1293499403.

Answer (score 0):

date() needs at least one parameter. see the doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php. you have error outputting disabled in your php.ini. check your log - its actually throwing an error

Comment: Not relevant to the actual problem, but: PHP 5.3.1/Windows: `Warning: date() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given`.